# Is it possible to run "git sync" again once I get permission to access some repos?

Tags: android, repo

I ran the command "repo sync --optimized-fetch" and found out I need permission for cloning some of the repos. Then I got the permission the second day, is it good to run "repo sync --optimized-fetch" again, will it clone the missing repos previously due to missing permission? or maybe I should ask if is it ok to run "repo sync --optimized-fetch" multiple times to resolve all unable-to-clone repos before?
Thanks!

Comment: Doesn't actually sound like a `git` question. What is `repo`?

Comment: sorry, my mistake, shouldn't be git question.

Comment: I think the title of the question should be edited as well.